# Write IAM Policy in which any user with full access of EC2 cannot delete instance of any other user in AWS account

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-opsworks

I want to write IAM policy in which any user with full access of ec2 is not permitted to terminate instance of any other user.

Second scenario : If i'm a normal user in aws  (with all privileges except IAM and Admin access )I want to list instance I had created and other user instance are not visible to me. Eg In Azure when i give resource level access to any other user he's not able to list see other user activities.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "ThisLimitAccessToOwnerAccess",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:RebootInstances",
            "ec2:StopInstances",
            "ec2:TerminateInstances",
            "ec2:StartInstances",
            "ec2:AttachVolume",
            "ec2:DetachVolume"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789:instance/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:ResourceTag/Owner": "${aws:username}"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

(edited to correct formatting)